# HTML5 app collision and printing issue

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I was messing around thinking for ideas for games in JS, I made a small little app that just draws boxes on a canvas, I was trying to add collision (which ive done before on different apps) but for some reason something is going wrong. I dont know what to do as the results of the code are very odd (collision code is under the collision function at the bottom of the code). I also had a problem with printing stuff on the boxes I created which I also found to be really weird (jsfiddle line 30). Would appreciate some help!

---

**Printing issue :**

```
function drawBoxes(coords,ctx){
    var colorArray = ["#1abc9c","#2ecc71","#3498db","#9b59b6","#34495e","#f1c40f","#e67e22","#e74c3c","#95a5a6"];
    console.log(coords);
    for(var i=0;i<=100;i++){
        var coordinates = coords[i].split(",");
        ctx.fillStyle = colorArray[Math.floor((Math.random() * 8) + 1)];
        ctx.fillRect(coordinates[0],coordinates[1],coordinates[2],coordinates[3]);
        ctx.fillStyle = "#000000";
        ctx.font = "20px arial";    
        ctx.fillText(coordinates[0] + "," + coordinates[1],coordinates[0]+10,coordinates[1]+31);
    }
}
```

---

**Collision issue**

```
function collision(coords,c,ctx){
    $(document).click(function(e){
        if(e.target == c){
            for(var i=0;i<=100;i++){
                var coordinates = coords[i].split(",");
                if((e.offsetY > coordinates[1] && e.offsetY < coordinates[1]+50) && (e.offsetX > coordinates[0] && e.offsetX < coordinates[0]+50)){
                    ctx.fillStyle = "#ffffff";
                    ctx.fillRect(coordinates[0],coordinates[1],coordinates[2],coordinates[3]);
                } 
            }
        }
    });
}
```

---

Both these functions are called from the main function which is called at the start of the code.
https://jsfiddle.net/9utyp7bm/

Comment: I dont know how to bump :@

Comment: Looking at your code and your app you are clearing out the squares, however you haven't stated what you would like it to do / what is wrong.